# C-vector space V linear transformation T: V → V . Show that the image + kernel is a direct sum.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

A linear transformation of C-vector space (complex field) where $T: V → V$  and $T ◦ T = −2T$.

$$\dim(V) = n$$

How can we prove that $\operatorname{Im}(T) + \ker(T)$ is direct?
I know that i have to show that their intersection is $0$ and that $\operatorname{Im}(T) + \ker(T) = V$ but i can't seem to use the information they've given to me.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $v \in Im(T) \cap ker(T)$ and $v \neq 0$. Then there exists a vector $w$ such  that $Tw = v$ and $T^2w = Tv = 0$. But $T^2 = -2T$ thus $$0 = T^2w = -2Tw = -2v$$ implying $v = 0$, contradicting our hypothesis.

Hence $Im(T) \cap ker(T) = \{ 0 \}$